# awk syntax error unexpected new line or end of string

Tags: awk

This
`/usr/sbin/conntrack -L |grep $1 | grep ESTAB |grep 'dport=80' | awk "{system("/usr/sbin/conntrack -D --orig-src $1 --orig-dst" substr($6,5) "-p tcp --orig-port-src " substr($7,7)" --orig-port-dst 80");}"`

gives this output
`awk: cmd. line:2: {system(/usr/sbin/conntrack
awk: cmd. line:2:                            ^ unexpected newline or end of string`

I need to debug this.

Comment: fun fact, the whole `grep ESTAB |grep 'dport=80' | awk '` construct could be replaced with `awk '/ESTAB/&&/dport=80/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `awk` script:

```
awk "{system("/usr/sbin/conntrack -D --orig-src $1 --orig-dst" substr($6,5) "-p tcp --orig-port-src " substr($7,7)" --orig-port-dst 80")}"
```

The script has an issue with quoting:

The script is in double quotes, and it also uses double quotes.  The internal double quotes will cause problems.

The solution is to write the script in single quotes (`awk` scripts should always be in single quotes anyway so that `$0` etc. is not interpreted by the shell):

```
awk '{system("/usr/sbin/conntrack -D --orig-src " $1 " --orig-dst " substr($6,5) " -p tcp --orig-port-src " substr($7,7) " --orig-port-dst 80")}'
```

You may also easily move the last two `grep` calls you're doing into the `awk` script:

```
awk '/ESTAB/ && /dport=80/ {system("/usr/sbin/conntrack -D --orig-src " $1 " --orig-dst " substr($6,5) " -p tcp --orig-port-src " substr($7,7) " --orig-port-dst 80");}'
```

And with a bit more work, you can get the first one in there as well:

```
awk -v arg1="$1" 'match($0, arg1) && /ESTAB/ && /dport=80/ {system("/usr/sbin/conntrack -D --orig-src " $1 " --orig-dst " substr($6,5) " -p tcp --orig-port-src " substr($7,7) " --orig-port-dst 80")}'
```

Comment: Now, conntrack says [code]Invalid IP address `--orig-dst'[/code]

Comment: @DudusBlack It looks like `--orig-src $1 --orig-dst` should be `--orig-src " $1 " --orig-dst`. Further than that, I don't know. `conntrack` is an unknown command for me.

Comment: @DudusBlack You may also want to make sure that you get the other spaces right in the string.  For example `--orig-dist "` rather than `--orig-dist"`.

Comment: Thanks. They should have a "thumbs up". You're great help. It probably would have cost me a day and some hair.

Comment: @DudusBlack Upvoting and/or accepting the answer is more than enough :-)

Comment: 15 reps bruh. 15. And i can't even do 1 situp yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the conntrack TCP entries that have a source IP address of `$1` (the first parameter to your script), an original destination port 80 and an `ESTABLISHED` state, that should just be:

```
conntrack -D -s "$1" -p tcp --dport 80 --state ESTABLISHED
```

beside the issues already mentioned, your approach would match on lines that have `dport=8080` as well or lines that have `dport=80` in the *reply-to* dst. And `$1` in `"--orig-src " $1` would be the first field in the line as expanded by `awk`, not the first argument of the script. Also, `grep 10.1.1.4` would match on `10.1.1.40` and `10.101.4.5` even with `grep -w` (`.` as a regexp operator matches any character, and is not a *word* character).

If `conntrack` didn't have the ability to filter entries by itself, you'd rather  do something like:

```
conntrack -L | SRC=$1 awk '
  $1 == "tcp" && \
  $4 == "ESTABLISHED" && \
  $5 == "src=" ENVIRON["SRC"] && \
  $8 == "dport=80" {
    dst = substr($6, 5)
    sport = substr($7, 7)
    system("conntrack -D -s \"$SRC\" -d "dst" --dport 80 --sport "sport)
  }'
```

Or to avoid running one `sh` command per entry to delete (in addition to one `conntrack` command):

```
conntrack -L | SRC=$1 awk '
  $1 == "tcp" && \
  $4 == "ESTABLISHED" && \
  $5 == "src=" ENVIRON["SRC"] && \
  $8 == "dport=80" {
    dst = substr($6, 5)
    sport = substr($7, 7)
    print "conntrack -D -s \"$SRC\" -d "dst" --dport 80 --sport "sport
  }' | sh
```